# Count all possible paths from top left to bottom right

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

The task is to count all the possible paths from top left to bottom right of a mXn matrix with the constraints that from each cell you can either move only to right or down.

```
     int[][] count = new int[n][m];
     int i,j;

     for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
         count[i][0] = 1;
     for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
         count[0][i] = 1;

     for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
         for (j = 1; j < m; j++)
             count[i][j] = (count[i - 1][j] + count[i][j - 1]);

     System.out.println(count[n - 1][m - 1]);
```

The above code shows the wrong answers for large values of m and n.
Using long arrays is also not working.
In one of the correct solutions, the formula 
`count[i][j]=(count[i-1][j]+count[i][j-1])%(**(int)Math.pow(10,9)+7)**;
is used!
I cannot understand the reason for the same.

Comment: No need for any loops. The answer can be obtained from a simple equation involving the values m and n.

Comment: Your claim that a valid solution uses `%((int)Math.pow(10,9)+7)` cannot be correct, unless you left something out of the problem description, because calculating intermediate results using modulo will otherwise give the wrong result.

Comment: Yaa.. I kinda left that thing...they have mentioned it at the end of the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Testing with a square size and using `int`, you can calculate up to 17x17. With 18x18 you get numeric overflow.

To detect the numeric overflow, change the following line:

```
count[i][j] = (count[i - 1][j] + count[i][j - 1]);
```

To:

```
count[i][j] = Math.addExact(count[i - 1][j], count[i][j - 1]);
```

Running with 18x18 you then get `java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow`, while 17x17 prints `601080390`.

Changing to `long` raises the limit to 34x34 = `7219428434016265740`, and 35x35 fails.

To go beyond that, use `BigInteger`:

```
private static void count(int n, int m) {
    BigInteger[][] count = new BigInteger[n][m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        count[i][0] = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        count[0][i] = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j < m; j++)
            count[i][j] = count[i - 1][j].add(count[i][j - 1]);
    System.out.println(n + "x" + m + ": " + count[n - 1][m - 1]);
}
```

You can now calculate for very large sizes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 10; i < 150; i+=10)
        count(i,i);
}
```

*Output*

```
10x10: 48620
20x20: 35345263800
30x30: 30067266499541040
40x40: 27217014869199032015600
50x50: 25477612258980856902730428600
60x60: 24356699707654619143838606602026720
70x70: 23623985175715118288974865541854103729000
80x80: 23156006494021191956342707682359261381151378400
90x90: 22880174247360071687155809670095748237789263482394000
100x100: 22750883079422934966181954039568885395604168260154104734000
110x110: 22738029575969641265497648088901902565550598643635116137437818400
120x120: 22820983692956015651850538861400483591556161461874723704379950728024000
130x130: 22985198722890636106807214387141205118592781510195606858610359655612113472140
140x140: 23220197341838572012462842682887166477737842005968501197039194284526789533662125200
```

Comment: What if I am not allowed to import the library for BigInteger?

Comment: @user3083913 Then you can't do it beyond the value range of a `long`. Use `long` and use `Math.addExact`, so at least it'll error out on overflow, instead of returning invalid result.

Answer (score 0):

It takes m + n - 2 steps to travel from top left to bottom right of an m x n grid via only right and down steps: m - 1 steps right, and n - 1 steps down.  Each distinct path is characterized by a particular choice of which of those steps is down (equivalently: which of those steps is right).  There is an analytic solution for that:

```
factorial(m + n - 2) / (factorial(m - 1) * factorial(n - 1))
```

You may recognize that as the m-1<sup>th</sup> binomial coefficient of order m + n - 2.

You don't need to compute it that way, of course, and in fact, you need to exercise great care if you want to do so, because the factorial grows *extremely* rapidly.  And that's why I bring it up: by whatever means you compute it, the result grows rapidly for m close to n, exceeding the range of `long` pretty quickly -- albeit exponentially, not factorially.

> In one of the correct solutions, the formula `count[i][j]=(count[i-1][j]+count[i][j-1])%((int)Math.pow(10,9)+7); is used! I cannot understand the reason for the same.

That would not be used in a correct solution to the problem you have presented, but I have seen a modified version of this problem where it would make sense: one where you are asked to compute the result ***modulo 1000000007***, which is exactly what the bit that has confused you does.  I think I've seen that on Project Euler, but it may be other places, too.  That variation on the problem allows one to completely avoid the issue of unrepresentable integers on any system that has a 32-bit integer type.